# VMWare and Turnkey Linux appliance can't access network

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking

I have a VMWare ESXi cluster running many Windows and Linux VMs perfectly.  I have installed the Turnkey Linux Redmine appliance, and am having a lot of trouble getting the networking to work properly.

The appliance VM is set up to use VLAN12, which is the same VLAN as my PC, unfortunately when the VM tries to ping anything outside itself, I get a "destination host unreachable".  This is the same when I try to ping the VM from my PC.

ifconfig output:

```
eth0

Link enap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:8b:5a:06
inet addr:10.7.12.234  Bcast:10.7.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr:fe80::250:56ff:fe8b:5a06/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500 Metric:1
...
```

route output:

```
Destination     Gateway          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.7.12.0       *                255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         10.7.12.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

My PC's (Windows) ipconfig output

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d03:24a4:4378:a203%13
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.7.12.23
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.7.12.1
```

I've read a lot of people having issues with Ubuntu (which I believe is what the appliance is based on), VMware and the network problem but the solution tends to be "switch to bridged mode."  I don't have those options in VMWare - just the VLAN options.

Can anyone shed any light on this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You say that other VMs run perfectly. Are they- or at least some of them- in 10.7.12.0/24, i.e. VLAN 12, or is this Turnkey appliance the only one? Is the Turnkey appliance connected to a port group where other VMs that work fine are connected, too?

Answer (score 0):

I know you've stated that the pinging from your linux server to your PC on the same subnet isn't possible but that seems bizzare.. A couple of things to check and post back:

1. Ping from the linux host to a) your desktop PC b) your gateway c) an internet host (e.g. 8.8.8.8) and post the results.
2. Ping from your PC to a) the linux host b) your gateway c) an internet host (e.g. 8.8.8.8) and post the results.
3. Check the virtual machine settings and find out what version of virtual NIC your VM has (e.g. VMWare or Intel) and post back.

I know you may well have done all this already but it may possible shed some light on it. Also, was your Virtual Appliance copied from another VM or installed from an OVF template? If it was copied make sure the MAC address wasn't copied from one VM to the other inadvertently.

Answer (score -3):

Before boot machine, look at network options in wmvare, and experiment set to NAT or bridget, in my case that always solve problems with download appliances

Comment: There is no NAT mode in ESXi. All traffic is bridged.